# In asynchronous callbacks, how does the caller know when it is being called back?

Tags: callback

If I understand asynchronous callbacks correctly, the opposite, sychronous, is when you call a function, wait, it is done, notifies the caller (it's calling back), then the program continues.  Why that is different from a regular function call I don't know.  But, if I am correct the program sits there until the callback is done.

In asynchronous, the callback is called and the program is continuing along.  How does the initial caller know when the callback is done?  It's already passed where the callback was called from.

I suppose I don't really know how a regular synchronous callback is known either.  I'm just used to it.

Can anyone explain this?

Yes, I have read many SO questions about this.  I *think* I understand them.  I'm curious about the underlying engine.  Does it put it on the stack and periodically "look" or poll for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I understand asynchronous callbacks correctly, the opposite, sychronous, is when you call a function, wait, it is done, notifies the caller (it's calling back), then the program continues.

That is correct.

> Why that is different from a regular function call I don't know

A regular function call isn't a callback.  A callback is a separate function that is provided and will be called by the callee.  If the callback is synchronous, it will be processed before control returns to the caller. For example:

```
public static void callback() {}

public static void main() {
    int i = anotherFunction(callback);
}
```

In this case, if anotherFunction() treats the callback as synchronous, callback will be called and will return prior to anotherFunction() returning.

> But, if I am correct the program sits there until the callback is done.

Correct.

> In asynchronous, the callback is called and the program is continuing along. How does the initial caller know when the callback is done? It's already passed where the callback was called from.

By definition, the caller of a function yielding an asynchronous callback **does not know** when the callback will occur, and **cannot guarantee** that the callback will ever occur.  If your control flow shouldn't continue until this callback occurs, you'll need to use some sort of event signaling or locking mechanism to prevent flow from continuing until the callback occurs.

> I suppose I don't really know how a regular synchronous callback is known either.

This is known because the function taking the callback should be a blocking call, so the caller won't proceed until the call returns.

Comment: Thanks.  So when I see callbacks in things like Drupal, WordPress, something else in a server side language for the web, PHP, Python, C#, etc., those are synchronous functions that were registered somewhere (database, configuration file, whatever.)  Right?

Comment: I'd need a specific example to see for sure.  It will differ case by case.  Ideally, the API will indicate if the callback is asynchronous or async.

Comment: I didn't think anything but node.js was asynch.

Answer (score 1):

> sychronous, is when you call a function, wait, it is done, notifies
>   the caller (it's calling back), then the program continues. Why that
>   is different from a regular function call I don't know.

A synchronous function is the same as a regular function. Regular functions "block" the program meaning the code in the function needs to finish executing before moving to the code after the function call.

With asynchronous functions, what you do is you register the function with some event handler, and the code after this registration **doesn't care** about the return value of the function (the function isn't even run yet, and may never run!).

A good example might be in Javascript where you make a network request, and your callback function is called only when the request completes successfully. You might even have a callback function for when there is an error, so just registering an async function does not mean it will be called (in this case either the success callback or the error callback will be executed).

Another example might be a Javascript callback for when a user clicks somewhere on the page (this might never happen). If they do click, maybe you want to modify the page, and your callback function will completely handle this.

```
How does the initial caller know when the callback is done?
```

The caller doesn't know this (and doesn't care either). The caller's only job was to setup the callback, so that the code inside the callback could appropriately handle whatever event it's registered for happens.

Comment: Thanks.  So are those just wrapper functions of a sort for async. functions?  I guess that's one way to think about it anyway.

Comment: "So are those just wrapper function" what do you mean "those"?

Comment: The functions that register the async. functions.

Comment: They don't wrap the function. They just take the function as an argument and store it inside their class. Then when the class notices the event happened, it looks for that variable that is holding a reference to the callback function, and calls it.